# How are inline-elements treated differently when they're flex-items & grid-items?

Tags: html, css

I’ve noticed some strange behaviours when inline elements are my grid&flex-items. You can set `width` and `height` on them (and they'll successfully respond to that). Also, in flexbox, when inline’s `width: auto` it’ll expand inline element to the size of the container/flex-line - as if it were a block element.

I’ve read somewhere that flex and grid items are blocksified. Is this true and if so what does it mean?

Comment: Because in flex or grid containers they aren't inline elements any more. They are flex or grid elements.

Comment: @Paulie_D I’ve read somewhere that flex and grid items are blocksified. Is this true and if so what does it mean?